# Spring MVC Component Scan

Tags: spring-mvc

Using SpringSource Tool Suite 2.9.2, I created a project with

> New > Spring Template Project > Spring MVC Project

This generates a simple controller, pom.xml, servlet-context.xml, root-context.xml, and a simple jsp file for the controller to map to.

When I run the project, however, the controller is not picked up by the component scan, although the `/resources/**` path is mapped to the resource servlet as specified in `servlet-context.xml`.  The page that should be giving me Hello World is giving me a 404.

What am I doing wrong?

The relevant bit in `servlet-context.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.hello" />
```

`com.test.hello.HomeController.java`:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", new Date());
        return "home";
    }
}
```

And the error message:

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Content of `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you show me your web.xml file here.

Comment: Have you configure DispatcherServlet with name appServlet??

Comment: Do you have the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your servlet-context.xml ?

Comment: @tofs servlet-context.xml has the line `<annotation-driven />`, and the IDE complains that the prefix `mvc:` is unbound when I try adding it.

Comment: You might be lacking `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` and under `xsi:schemaLocation` - `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd`

Answer (score 2):

A simple Clean and Build of the Project has fixed this Issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

Please changes this line `<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.hello.*" />`

It not scanning your controller Also please specify what url using for applications