# spring mvc-requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying spring mvc example and i am not able to transfer the control from jsp to the controller class.My controller class is as follows

CController.java

```
package project4;

import project4.UserDAO1;
import project4.User1;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/frm4")


public class CController{

    private UserDAO1 userDAO;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myUserDAO")
    private UserDAOImpl1 myUserDAO;

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO1 userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView add( @ModelAttribute("add") User1 user,HttpServletRequest 
            request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        userDAO.saveUser(user);
        System.out.println("hai");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView delete(@ModelAttribute("delete") User1 user,HttpServletRequest 
            request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            userDAO.deleteUser(user);
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
     }


    @RequestMapping(params = "find", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView find(@ModelAttribute("find") User1 user,HttpServletRequest 
            request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
                     userDAO.findUser(user);
                      return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }


    @RequestMapping(params = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("update") User1 user,HttpServletRequest
             request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
                     userDAO.updateUser(user);
                      return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }

     public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        modelMap.addAttribute("userList", userDAO.listUser());
        modelMap.addAttribute("user", new User1());
        return new ModelAndView("userForm", modelMap);
    }
 }
```

and the jsp page is as follows

frm4.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="add.do">
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td><label for="id">Id:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input  name="id" value="${user.id}" />
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <label for="name">Name:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input name="name" value="${user.name}" />
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
            <label for="password">Password:</label></td>
         <td>
             <input name="password" value="${user.password}" />
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
           <td>
              <label for="gender">Gender:</label></td>
           <td>
               <input name="gender" value="${user.gender}" />
           </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <label for="lastName">Country:</label></td>
          <td>
            <input name="country" value="${user.country}" />
          </td>
       </tr>

     </table> 
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

i am not using spring form tag in jsp(because it is throwing me "neither binding nor plain target object "error).So when i run this program i am getting the following error as

```
type Status report

message 

description The requested resource () is not available.
```

and i am getting the url as

```
http://localhost:8080/Spring/add.do
```

where Spring is my project name under which i have stored the program.I have placed the CController.java controller class under "project4" folder in src.I have placed frm4.jsp and list.jsp under WebContent.

EDIT:

i tried

```
<form method="POST" action="CController/add.do">
```

and

```
<form method="POST" action="Spring/CController/add.do">
```

but the error remains the same

Comment: `action = "frm4/add.do"` ?

Comment: i tried tht too but error remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined any request mapping for `/add`

You just have `/frm4` and you are separating actions by param names like add, delete, etc.

For this to work use `action="/frm4"` and in the form add a **hidden param name** `add`.

But I would advice to change it to **separate urls** like **frm4/add, frm4/delete, etc**.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: i changed it to @RequestMapping(value="frm4/add" , method = RequestMethod.POST) but the error remains the same

Comment: Note the value should be /add and not frm4/add as your controller at the top already have /frm4.

Answer (score 1):

man you have to set action in form to "/frm4"

and change

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Submit"/>
```

and

```
@ModelAttribute("add") User1 user
```

to

```
@ModelAttribute User1 user
```

please check these [videos](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7350712B99EFC5DD)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<context:component-scan base-package="<YOUR PACKAGE HERE>"/>` in your spring config for spring to scan for annotations if not already done.

Similar Issue: [Spring MVC Component Scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812303/spring-mvc-component-scan)